# Sort and join files in AIX

Tags: sorting, join, aix

I have two sample files test1.txt and text2.txt. How to join them appropriately ?

```
$> cat test1.txt
1 USA
2 CANADA
3 MEXICO
4 BAHAMAS
5 CUBA


$> cat test2.txt
MEXICO Mexico-city
USA Washington
CANADA Ottawa
CUBA Havanna
BAHAMAS Nassau

$> join -j 2 -o '1.1,1.2,2.2' < (sort -k2 test1.txt) < (sort -k1 test2.txt)
ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `(' is not expected.
```

Expected output:

```
1 USA Washington
2 CANADA Ottawa
3 MEXICO Mexico-city
4 BAHAMAS Nassau
5 CUBA Havanna
```

Comment: `< (` and `<(` are two completely different things.

Comment: I tried both  $> join -j 2 -o '1.1,1.2,2.2' <(sort -k2 test1.txt) <(sort -k1 test2.txt)
ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `(' is not expected.

Comment: What version of KSH is it? Do you have a more recent one installed (`ksh93`?), or bash?

Comment: yes, Mat is onto the problem. `ksh` on AIX is the `88` original flavor. You'll have to find `ksh93` and use an appropriate "shebang" line (maybe `#!/bin/ksh93` at the top of your script to have access to the `<( cmd )` notation. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is bad! When the test1.txt file is large, you will have too much overhead in calling `grep` and `cut` for each line.

```
while read -r line; do
   key=${line#* }
   printf "%s %s\n" "${line}" $(grep "${key}" test2.txt | cut -d" " -f2-)
done < test1.txt
```

You should get your join working or use awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { towns[$1]=$2; next;} $2 in towns {print $0 " " towns[$2];}' test2.txt test1.txt
```